# I can't fix this: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

When I try to run the following code I get a '`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`'

```
ResultSet res = null;
    String[] waarden = new String[20];
    int length = 0;
    String query = "SELECT rd_datum, rd_locatie FROM racedag;";
    res = Database.executeSelectQuery(query);
    try{
        while (res.next()){
            int i = 1;
            waarden[i] = res.getString(1);
            i++;
            waarden[i] = res.getString(2);
            i++;
        }

        }
    catch (Exception e){
            }
    finally{
        length = waarden.length;
    }
    String eindWaarden[] = new String[length];
    for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
        eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
    }
    return eindWaarden;
}
```

and I have no clue why.

Comment: Because the array index is out of bounds?

Comment: This piece of code is most likely not going to do what you want it to do. You are keeping only the values of the last row. If there are multiple rows in the result, you'll only see the values of the last row.

Comment: You have an empty catch block: DON'T DO IT! Put at least some logging there or you will be staring at you screen many hours wondering why it's not working.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't shown where the exception is occurring, but for one thing you're only *ever* writing to `waarden[1]` and `waarden[2]` (as `i` is declared inside the `while` loop). I doubt that that's deliberate.

Also, your exception handling is terrible - just catching exceptions and doing *nothing* is a bad idea, as is catching `Exception` itself in most cases.

Then there's this problem:

```
String eindWaarden[] = new String[length];
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++) {
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

That will *always* fail, because you're accessing `eindWaarden[length]`, which will be off the end of the array. Valid indexes are `0` to `length - 1` inclusive. If you want to keep that loop (which I doubt) change the `<=` to `<`.

Oh, and `length` is always going to be 20, however many results you retrieved - because that's the length of `waarden`.

Also, while this declaration is *valid*:

```
String eindWaarden[]
```

it's generally discouraged as a matter of style. Keep all the type information together, just as you did for `waarden`.

Your code would be *much* better if you'd just use a `List<String>` instead:

```
String query = "SELECT rd_datum, rd_locatie FROM racedag;";
ResultSet res = Database.executeSelectQuery(query);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
// Removed try block: declare that your method throws SqlException or whatever
while (res.next()) {
    results.add(res.getString(1));
    results.add(res.getString(2));
}
// Change the method declaration to have a return type of List<String>
return results;
```

Comment: I should have known you would edit your answer to include a remark about `waarden[1]` and `waarden[2]`. Would have saved me the effort of mentioning the exact same thing ...

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
        eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
    }
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
        eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you are trying to access an element in an array with an invalid index (the index is outside of the range `0` to `array.length - 1`).

The bug is in this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
```

That should have been:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last for loop you say i <= length, which I believe should just be i < length

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems with the code, the this is what's causing the exception:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
```

Change the `<=` to `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
```

Comment: at max it give back 4 rows, since the database is still very empty.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

With

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

(`<` instead of `<=`)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:

I'm just gonna come out and say it. This code returns a 20-element array of `String`, of which the first element is empty, and the next two elements will be populated with the last row returned from the given query. All the other elements in the array are empty.

Since SQL doesn't *necessarily* guarantee the order of results (unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause) you could get a random row each time.

This whole thing could be rewritten as:

```
final int length = 20;
String[] waarden = new String[20];
final String query = "SELECT rd_datum, rd_locatie FROM racedag LIMIT 1";
ResultSet res = Database.executeSelectQuery(query);

try {
    if (res.next()) {
        waarden[1] = res.getString(1);
        waarden[2] = res.getString(2);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
}

return waarden;
```

This probably isn't what you meant to do though...

Comment: Note that `i` is set to `1` inside the loop each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<` instead of `<=` in your for loop. Otherwise, you are trying to access an index which doesn't exist:

```
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

replace with

```
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
    eindWaarden[i] = waarden[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
```

An array has N elements, with index going from 0 to N-1.

So the correct one is:

```
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which is already addressed in the other answers, and the very bad error handling as mentioned by @JonSkeet there is also this piece of code

```
try{
    while (res.next()){
        int i = 1;
        waarden[i] = res.getString(1);
        i++;
        waarden[i] = res.getString(2);
        i++;
    }

    }
catch (Exception e){
        }
finally{
    length = waarden.length;
}
```

Is there any good reason your `waarden` array has a length of `20` if you only put values at index `1` and index `2`. Looking at the rest of your code you expect `waarden` to get fully populated with the results of your query, which will not be the case. You probably want to move the `int i = 1` outside the `while` loop and initialize it at `0` instead of `1`. This will only work if you are certain the number of results will never exceed `10` or your `waarden[]` is simply too small